# Boolean algebra when used

Tags: boolean-logic

I am new to Boolean algebra, I want to know when is Boolean algebra used. I am getting confused with it. Please, anyone can clear it so I can understand? Is Boolean algebra using to simplify mathematical calculation during execution of user program or already used in designed circuit board of computer?

Answer (score 0):

Boolean algebra is used for elementary digital circuits composed of logical gates (AND, OR, NOT, XOR, ...). But it also is applied in many other fields.
Examples include philosophy, literature/search retrieval, software engineering, software verification, logic synthesis, automatic test pattern generation, artificial intelligence, logic in general, discrete mathematics, combinatorics, discrete optimization, constraint programming, game theory, information theory, coding theory ... to name a few.

An overview of Boolean algebra applications is listed in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Applications_2).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: **both**.

Boolean algebra is a science, derived from the name of [George Boole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole), a mathematician, logician and philosopher, who laid the foundation of two-valued logic.

[Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra) is the study of mathematical symbols and the rules of manipulating those symbols via formulas.

Therefore, [Boolean Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) is the field of study that focuses on mathematical symbols and the rules of manipulating those symbols via formulas on the domain of 2-valued logical expressions whose foundations were laid down by George Boole.

The most atomic principle of Boolean Algebra is that a statement may be true or false and nothing else. True is represented by 1 and false is represented by 0. Let's see a few expressions

```
A and B = A * B
```

that is, A and B is true if and only if both values are true, that is, 1 * 1 = 1, but 1 * 0 <> 1, 0 * 1 <> 1 and 0 * 0 <> 1.

```
A or B = A + B - A * B
```

Since we are in the domain of two values, A or B has to be either 0 or 1. So, we exclude A * B from the result of their addition to cover the case when both A and B is true, which would now be evaluated to 1 + 1 - 1 = 1.

These logical formulas and many others are covered in electronic circuits via [logical gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate), but this field of study is used by you at every day of your life as well, but you do not necessarily realize it.

Whenever you assume that a statement is fully true or fully false, you are in line with Boolean algebra. When you draw a conclusion, you are operating with the logical operator called **implication**.

Basically, more often than not, when you use logic, you partially or fully apply Boolean standards (hopefully).

So, Boolean Algebra is the field if study that operates with statements. And since science and everyday life is all about thoughts/statements, Boolean Algebra is everywhere, you cannot escape it.

**The more interesting question is: if Boolean Algebra is so prevalent, then what is the context of non-Boolean logic?**

And the answer is simple. Whenever we operate with the probability of the unknown or partial truths.

If you toss a coin, you know for sure that it will be either a head or a tail, but, before tossing the coin you do not know which one, so you compute the probability, which is 0.5 for each case.

If you throw a dice, then you know that it will either be a six or something else. You do not know in advance whether it will be a six or something else, but you know that there is a 1/6 probability that it will be a six.

Probability is a value between 0 and 1. You can convert the raw probability value that is between 0 and 1 to the more popular % value by multiplying its value with 100. So, the probability of a heads as a result of a coin toss would be (0.5 * 100) % = 50%.

So, probability calculation deals with the unkown, even if the statements would eventually become boolean statements, before some events they cannot be fully evaluated, but they can be predicted to some extend. So, this is the field of probability calculation.

Statistics is the field that assumes that the frequency of events in a larg input pattern that's known from the past can predict the future. It's a case of applied probabilities. This is also a non-boolean approach to statements.

Fuzzy logic (no, this is not a joke, there is actually a field of study that goes by this name) deals with partial truths. If you are during the process of eating your lunch, then it is not true that you ate your lunch, neither that you did not eat your lunch, because you have eaten a part of it and you have completed it to a certain extent. So, Fuzzy logic is also a multi-valued field of study, which deals with partial truths.

## Conclusion

Boolean algebra is used everywhere, including the areas you have been wondering about and much more. So, Boolean algebra is used both in the circuits and mathematical computations. The very bits that comprise any information (except for the esotheric qbits, but in order not to confuse you I will not delve into that area here) are statements on their own. A 0 means lack of current and a 1 means the presence of current. So, if we have a number represented on 8 bits (for the sake of simplicity), that's a set of 8 statements that ultimately results in the representation of a number.

For example, a 15 is represented (on 8 bits) as

00001111

because

> 15
>
> = 0 * 1^7 + 0 * 1^6 + 0 * 1^5 + 0 * 1^4 + 1* 1^3 + 1 * 1^2 + 1 * 1^1 + 1 * 1^1
>
> = 0 * 128 + 0 * 64 + 0 * 32 + 0 * 16 + 1 * 8 + 1 * 4 + 1 * 2 + 1 * 1

So even the numbers you see in front of you  on the computer are evaluated with Boolean algebra.