# How can I test three conditions in a when clause?

Tags: ansible

My requirement is to execute a command if three conditions satisfy. But the below condition does not work as expected

```yaml
when: (count.stdout == 0 and type == 0 and operat.sdtout == "AIX")
```

As far as I could check, all three values should pass the relevant tests but the task is still skipping. What is the problem with that condition?

Comment: Please make the above a [mre]. Specifically, create a playbook where you debug the value of the different variables and show the output. Please do not add this information in comments, edit your question. Meanwhile, here is a wild guess: you are using a variable which apparently registers the result of a command. In that case `stdout` will always be a string. You are comparing that value to an int. So you might want to try `count.stdout == "0"` or eventually `count.stdout | int == 0`. Note that you might have the same issue for the variable `type`.

Comment: Assuming you want to have 3 conditions to be verified you may try: (count.stdout == "0") and (type == 0) and (operat.sdtout == "AIX")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `count.stdout` and `type` are meant as boolean values, a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    count:
      stdout: '0'
      stdout_lines:
        - '0'
    type: '0'
    operat:
      stdout: 'AIX'
      stdout_lines:
        - 'AIX'

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "All conditions met"
    when: not (count.stdout | bool) and not (type | bool) and (operat.stdout == 'AIX')
```

will result into the required behavior

```yaml
TASK [debug] ************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: All conditions met
```

---

**Background Information**

According [`ansible/plugins/filter/core.py` - `to_bool`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L81) will cast everything to `False` which is not in

```python
    if isinstance(a, string_types):
        a = a.lower()
    if a in ('yes', 'on', '1', 'true', 1):
        return True
    return False
```

So in your case, `0` will become `False` and since [the task should run only `when` is `True`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when) you'll need to negate (`not`).

- [Boolean variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#boolean-variables)
- [Conditionals based on variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-variables)
- [Boolean algebra when used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73094494/6771046)
- and many more ...

---

**Additionally**,

if there is much more output in `operat.stdout` you'll need to check for `('AIX' in operat.stdout)` or `(operat.stdout is search('AIX'))`.

See in example [How to search for a string or word in Ansible results?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707836/266568) or [Run an Ansible task only when the variable contains a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496911/).